# how to know how many implicit intents are selected by the system in android before launching the intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a list of books.So on click of book, providing implicit intent and letting the sytem to choose the suitable reader.My code is as follows..

```
File file = new File(path);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(intent);
```

Now every thing works fine.And system is showing compete action by using dialog.

Now before launching the activity I just want to know what all the readers systems is selected.And print them. Does anybody knows please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `PackageManager`. You can call `queryIntentActivities()` to get the list of activities that would be presented to the user. Make sure to set the flag `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY`, otherwise you won't get the same set of results that will be displayed to the user.